# Unable to add Composer dependency using PhpStorm in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, composer-php, phpstorm

The error is:

> Cannot run program "C:\Users\Shahzaib
>   Imtiaz\PhpstormProjects\CodeCept\composer.json" (in directory
>   "C:\Users\Shahzaib Imtiaz\PhpstormProjects\CodeCept"): 
>       CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application –

[image: Link to screenshot]

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: Error message is following: Cannot run program "C:\Users\Shahzaib Imtiaz\PhpstormProjects\CodeCept\composer.json" (in directory "C:\Users\Shahzaib Imtiaz\PhpstormProjects\CodeCept"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Add error message.

Comment: 1) Did you specify PHP Interpreter for this project? 2) Did you provide the path to `composer.phar` in Settings? Right now for whatever reason IDE is trying to execute `composer.json` directly -- which is obviously wrong. SO it must be misconfiguration from your end. https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Composer+Support+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne for me the error says : Cannot run program "C:\wamp\www\Laravel\artisan"

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late, but...

This issue could be a part of an incorrect composer command-line tools settings in the PHPStorm (or there was no configurations for that for your project).
[image]

***Possible cause:***

- PHPStorm calls an incorrect startup file.
- Incorrect composer installation on Windows.
- In Windows PHPStorm doesn't recognize the composer.phar file correctly
- In Windows in PHPStorm it's usually calling the composer.phar instead of calling the composer.bat file to run the specific command and an error occurs.

***Solution:***

One of the possible solutions:

**1.** I suggest you to install (or check your current installation) composer with the [special windows installer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)

**2.** Check Windows system Path variable and there must to be the basic path to the folder, where composer were installed:
(for me it is C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin)

**3.** Go to your PHPStorm **settings** (press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>)

**4.** Go to **Tools -> Command Line Tool Support -> Press Add button**

[image]

**5.** **Select the "Tool based on Symfony Console"** and press OK button:

[image]

**6.** Add an alias to composer (I am usually using composer or c aliases e.t.c)

**7.** Set the correct path to your php interpreter (in my case it is C:\xampp\php\php.exe )

**8.** Set the path to your (global i suppose) **bin** composer folder (in my case it is C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.bat) and you must to select a composer.bat file (NOT the composer.phar file) and press Ok.

**9.** Go to **Tools -> Run Command** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>) and run the command you wanted.

[image]

Hope it will help to someone!